# How to implement recursive method **at** object initialization?

Tags: javascript, recursion, this, bind

Say I have the following object:

```
const dog = {
  sound: 'woof',
  speak: function() {
    console.log(this.sound)
  }
}
```

How could I implement `dog.speak` recursively *within the initial object literal declaration?*

I could accomplish this by defining the `dog.speak` method outside of the initial object literal. E.g.:

```
const dog = {
  sound: 'woof'
}

const dog.speak = () => {
  console.log(dog.sound)
  window.setTimeout(dog.speak, 1000)
}
```

This works because there is no `this` concept here - the `sound` property explicitly belongs to `dog`. But I would prefer to define this all within the initial object literal.

To do so, I would need to preserve the `this` context via `.bind()`. But I'm struggling to identify where I would `.bind()` `dog` as `this` before making the recursive function call.

Answer (score 1):

**arrow function**

The preferred way is to use an arrow function which has lexical context, `this` -

```js
// ECMAScript >= 6

const dog = {
  sound: 'woof',
  speak: function() {
    console.log(this.sound)
    setTimeout(_ => this.speak(), 1000)
  }
}

dog.speak()
```

```
woof
woof
woof
...
```

**Function.prototype.bind**

Before arrow functions, `.bind`ing the function to a context was preferred -

```js
// ECMAScript >= 5

const dog = {
  sound: 'woof',
  speak: function() {
    console.log(this.sound)
    setTimeout(this.speak.bind(this), 1000)
  }
}

dog.speak()
```

```
woof
woof
woof
...
```

**context variable**

Before `.bind` was available you could store the context in a variable -

```js
// ECMAScript < 5

const dog = {
  sound: 'woof',
  speak: function() {
    console.log(this.sound)
    var ctx = this
    setTimeout(function() { ctx.speak() }, 1000)
  }
}

dog.speak()
```

```
woof
woof
woof
...
```

Or simply use `dog` directly -

```js
// ECMAScript < 5

const dog = {
  sound: 'woof',
  speak: function() {
    console.log(this.sound)
    setTimeout(function() { dog.speak() }, 1000)
  }
}

dog.speak()
```

```
woof
woof
woof
...
```

Comment: Instead of the context variable `ctx`, just refer to `dog` directly

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the comment ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
const dog = {
  sound: 'woof',
  speak: function() {
    console.log(this.sound)
    const speak = this.speak.bind(dog)
    window.setTimeout(speak, 1000)
  }
}
```

This accomplishes the objective within a single object literal.

We can `bind` the `dog` as `this` within the initial function call, which preserves the `this` context throughout all future function calls.

Prior attempts, such as:

```
const dog = {
  sound: 'woof'
}

const dog.speak = () => {
  console.log(dog.sound)
  window.setTimeout(dog.speak, 1000)
}
```

would lose their `this` context after the first function call. `this` would refer to `dog` on the first function call, then `window` on future calls.

Comment: [You could also just use an arrow function](https://jsbin.com/kubebajesu/1/edit?js,console). I prefer it because otherwise `dog.speak.bind(dog)` (or `this.foo.bind(this)` or any variation thereof) kind of looks like a sandwich. It's correct but weird because of the repetition of the object around the method.